# Git Diff with data on the command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, typescript

I'm creating an IDE for TypeScript http://alm.tools/. I'd really like a git diff gutter and actually have it working:

[image]

However it is based on running `git diff` on a *saved* file (`git diff -U0 path/to/the/file`) (and in fact [I am forced to save the file if it isn't saved](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/832bab61d078d083dfb642d8c27ba663cba8d32e/src/server/workers/external/gitService.ts#L37-L42))

I'd like to diff the `head` version of a file with some file I have only in my IDE memory and not yet commited to disk.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff I can't find a way.

Comment: create a temp file. the doc clearly stats : __between two files on disk.__

Comment: What about blobs. Can I send two blob datas on the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

In git you cant to it.

***Why?***

You need to understand how git diff works.
In very short (the commands i explain are not executed in the the same order as explained here, i made it much more simple for you to understand the process):

When you execute `git diff` git is making a list of known files. then it compare the file to the ones on the working directory (in real life it executing several diff commands for un-tracked, modified and deleted) and this is the list of modification you see.

Same process apply to the staging area as well.

Since git has to process physical files (you can read the full code here: (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c) you cannot use must have a file.

what you can do but its overkill in my opinion is to simulate the way git generate files and save the blob under `.git` folder without have a physical file on the disk. This can be done - having file under `.git` without a phisocal one but again you will need to execute something like 4-5 commands to crate this file. (`hash-object`, `sha1sum` etc)...

### ***Summary***

What you are asking is not possible without physical file which git can compare. git needs a path and a sha-1 for comparison and if you don't have a physical file it cannot be done.